# SpringBoot @RestController, Ambiguous mapping found

Tags: spring, rest, controller, spring-boot, ambiguous-call

Hi I have a simple RestController in my Sample:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping(name = "/getName", method = GET)
    public String getName() {
        return "MyName";
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/getNumber", method = GET)
    public Double getNumber(){
        return new Double(0.0);
    }
}
```

And I have SampleController for start SpringBoot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class SampleController {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I try to run SampleCotroller the following exception occur:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'personController' bean method 
public java.lang.Double com.web.communication.PersonController.getNumber()
to {[],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'personController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.web.communication.PersonController.getName() mapped.
```

Where the problem can be? There can not be more RequestMappings in one RestController?

Very thanks for reply

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to use `value` attribute to define the mapping. You've used `name` right now, which just provides a name to the mapping, but doesn't define any mapping at all. So currently both your methods are unmapped (in which case, both are mapped to same path). Change the methods to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getName", method = GET)
public String getName() {
    return "MyName";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getNumber", method = GET)
public Double getNumber(){
    return new Double(0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or You Can use,

```
@GetMapping("/getName")
```

It is the same usage of method with value,it is new version of specifying method ="POST" with request mapping value.

Answer (score 0):

In **RequestMapping(value="/name")** always use value for path not name.
You can use method wise also like 
**GETMapping("/getname")
PostMapping("/addname")**